# Signal handling from Driver to Application

Tags: linux, signals

I want to implement the signal handler that signal any inappropriate in the driver to Application through signalling. In other words, the Linux driver sends the signal to particular application.

Is there anyway you can implement that?

Thanks,
Dev Null

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use the more general SIGIO.